# How to send accessToken in Detect Intent Text API in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm developing my chatbot backend using detect intent API in Python, once the intent recognized, it goes to my webhook and gets the appropriate data.

here is my detectIntent code to get data from text

```
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, text, language_code='en-US'):
   session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient().from_service_account_file(
    'my_service_account_json.json')
   session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
   print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))
   text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
   query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
   response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
   data = MessageToDict(response.query_result)
   print (json.dumps(data, indent=4))
   response = parse_response(data)
   return response
```

> How can I sent access_token with it so that my webhook can identify
>   which user is accessing the bot

**P.S.** my webhook is looking for an  access token in this path

```
req.get("originalDetectIntentRequest").get("payload").get("user").get("accessToken")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything under the "payload" attribute is platform dependent. The Assistant platform puts user information under here, for example, and this is what your webhook is currently trying to process.

If you wanted to put the access token in the same place, you can pass a `query_params` named parameter to the call to `detect_intent()` along with the text you're querying, and anything else that may be relevant. ([Reference](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/api.html#dialogflow_v2.SessionsClient.detect_intent)) That parameter can be a dict and, if so, has to have the same field names as a [QueryParameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/QueryParameters) object.